# Convert tensor of size 768 to 128

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I want to make a projection to the tensor of shape `[197, 1, 768]` to `[197,1,128]` in pytorch using `nn.Conv()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a kernel size and stride of 6, as that’s the factor between the input and output temporal size:

```
x = torch.randn(197, 1, 768)
conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=6, stride=6)
out = conv(x)
print(out.shape)
> torch.Size([197, 1, 128])
```

[Solution Source](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/convert-tensor-of-size-768-to-128/134724)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using a wide flat kernel and/or combined with a specific stride. If you stick with a dilation of `1`, then the input/output spatial dimension relation is given by:

```
out = [(2p + x - k)/s + 1]
```

Where `p` is the padding, `k` is the kernel size and `s` is the stride. `[]` detonates the whole part of the quantity.

Applied here you have:

```
128 = [(2p + 768 - k)/s + 1]
```

So you would get:

```
p = 2*p + 768 - (128-1)*s # one off
```

If you impose `p = 0`, and `s = 6` you find `k = 6`

```
>>> project = nn.Conv2d(197, 197, kernel_size=(1, 6), stride=6)
>>> project(torch.rand(1, 197, 1, 768)).shape
torch.Size([1, 197, 1, 128])
```

---

Alternatively, a more straightforward - but different - approach is to learn a mapping using a fully connected layer:

```
>>> project = nn.Linear(768, 128)
>>> project(torch.rand(1, 197, 1, 768)).shape
torch.Size([1, 197, 1, 128])
```

Comment: Thanks. But in the first solution (Conv), i want "3" dimensions, not "4"

Comment: You can squeeze `dim=2` with `project(torch.rand(1, 197, 1, 768))[..., 0, :]`